# Adding previous row value to get current row based on a condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

| Received | Issued |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 20 | 0 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 25 | 0 |
| 30 | 4 |

Require

| Received | Issued | Remaining |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | 5 |
| 10 | 0 | 15 |
| 0 | 1 | 14 |
| 0 | 2 | 12 |
| 20 | 0 | 32 |
| 0 | 3 | 29 |
| 25 | 0 | 54 |
| 30 | 4 | 80 |

The remaining column is supposed to be calculated using ;
**remaining = previous (remaining) + received - issued**
i have tried shift, isnull() and different types of conditions but i'm not getting it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.cumsum()`:

```py
df["Remaining"] = (df["Received"] - df["Issued"]).cumsum()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Received  Issued  Remaining
0         5       0          5
1        10       0         15
2         0       1         14
3         0       2         12
4        20       0         32
5         0       3         29
6        25       0         54
7        30       4         80
```